# Airports near Stockholm

Tags: airports, stockholm

I'm flying from Stockholm in a while and I wonder what airports there are close to the capital?

Searching for "Stockholm aiports" brings up Arlanda Airport and Bromma Airport but Skavsta Airports shows up in the search results as well. Searching a bit more gives me Stockholm Västerås Airport as well. Are there even more airports in the Stockholm area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, those are the airports that are close to Stockholm. [Arlanda (ARN)](https://www.swedavia.se/arlanda/), [Bromma (BMA)](https://www.swedavia.se/bromma/), [Skavsta (NYO)](http://www.skavsta.se/sv/) and [Västerås (VST)](http://vasterasairport.se/) are included in the [STO airport code](https://www.kayak.com/Stockholm-All-airports-Airport.STO.ap.html). Note though that the time to the airports are quite different when travelling from Stockholm City, from 15 - 20 minutes to [Bromma Airport](https://www.swedavia.se/bromma/) and up to 90 minutes to [Västerås Airport](http://vasterasairport.se/).

Comment: It is amusing to read ‘close to Stockholm’ for Skavsta and Västerås but I guess bother are closer to Stockholm than Göteborg ;)

Comment: @Jan Yeah, I was about to write "close" to Stockholm but decided to skip the quotation marks. Maybe I should add them back ;)

Comment: Hey, it's closer to Stockholm than Hahn is to Frankfurt ...